# Having or has? What is the best way to say that sentence

Tags: tenses, sequence-of-tenses

I have one question, what is the best way to say that sentence below? Are both grammatically correct?

> He has been working on mobile development for 4 years and has published more than 15 apps.

or

> He has been working on mobile development for 4 years, having published more than 15 apps.

Comment: In English, *this* refers to future things in text; *that* only refers to past things. “How do I say this?”

Comment: The second part of the second question would in my opinion better match "He is an expert in mobile development, having published more than 15 apps in a 4 year period"

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence is fine. It can be given some journalistic oompah though by using a participial phrase. Like this:

> He has been working on mobile development for 4 years, publishing more than 15 apps.

Not like this:

> He has been working on mobile development for 4 years, having published more than 15 apps.

For same timespans, use present participle (the one ending in -ing). To place something in an anterior timespan, use past participle. A few more examples of the former:

> The team has worked on TG research for over 35 years, publishing more than 70 topic related publications.
>   Vlado has worked on the strip for the past few years, publishing more than 500 daily episodes on his blog.

Answer (score -1):

Both sentences are grammatically correct, neither is better exactly. One may be more appropriate than the other for a particular context / author purpose.

> He has been working on mobile development for 4 years and has
>   published more than 15 apps

This first example uses the conjunction 'and' to connect two clauses without implying any causal relationship. Meanwhile the second, by using the **perfect gerund** 'having published' in a subclause, expresses a degree of *causality* - he's worked there so long *because* he has published so many apps.

Similarly the first sentence sounds more neutral, factual. Having said all that I couldn't find much online to support these comments so this could just be my impression.

On an extremely personal level: If, for example, I were writing a summary of my work experience I would prefer the neutral, factual-sounding sentence.

Comment: No, there's no causality involved. Participle phrases always function as adjectives, adding description to the sentence. 
http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participlephrase.htm

Comment: Your example reads as if they would not have kept him there, had he not published that many

Comment: Your absolutely right @Talia, good explanation. Can't add comment to yours but maybe it would help to have an example of when it is appropriate to use a _perfect participle_, e.g. **He is well respected in his department, having published more than 15 apps.**